# Issue in payment method scope in uber api

Tags: uber-api

The **payment_methods_readonly** scope is coming invalid with GET https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `payment_methods_readonly` scope is deprecated. You should use the `request` scope which gives you access to the `/v1/payment-methods` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Uber API changelog](https://developer.uber.com/docs/change-log) and the [Scopes](https://developer.uber.com/docs/scopes) documentation page the payment_methods_readonly scope has been removed/deprecated:

> 2016-01-16 Change scope for GET /v1/payment-methods from
>   **payment_methods_readonly** to **request**